# Шаблон для организации работы на предприятии

Tags: windows-10, железо

В рамках данного вопроса, разобъю его на несколько разделов:
1.На предприятии встал вопрос об организации работы сотрудников с программным обеспечением, в формате подключения к 1 центральному компьютеру, который будет оснащен всем необходимым программным обеспечением(компьютер на базе Windows 10 Pro либо иной другой). Касательно программного обеспечения: стандартный пакет Office(excel,word,powerpoint), софт для SEO(KeyKollector,Seo spider), Adobe Photoshop, Adobe InDesign, CorelDraw. Формат работы состоит в том, что сотрудник подключается к компьютеру под своей учетной записью, и работает. Результат работы выкладывает например на файловый сервер либо в облачное хранилище. Одной из основных целей подобной организации работы является сократить количество закупленных лицензий программного обеспечения. Насколько возможен такой формат работы, если количество одновременно подключенных пользователей будет варьироваться от 5 до 10. По аппаратному обеспечению достаточно ли будет core i7(i9) с 64гб оперативной памяти DDR4, ssd 1-2Тб на базе Samsung 960.

---

2.Если подобный вариант не сработает, то возможен ли подобный вариант:
 2.1. Предприятие приобретает в аренду выделенный сервер(с описанной выше конфигурацией или иной) либо использует некий сервис предлагающий подобное, устанавливает на него необходимый софт и работает на нем, также как и описано ранее, за исключением того, что физически компьютер находится в ином месте. Нечто похожее на работу с сервисом Playkey, за исключением того, что мощности удаленного сервера используются для работы нескольких пользователей с установленным ПО.

---

3. Если не один из вариант не подошел из перечисленных, подскажите другие варианты для подобной цели. Либо посоветуйте сервисы, предлагающие подобный формат работы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По первому пункту: Microsoft - жадная контора и за одной десктопной виндой может работать только один человек. Не важно локально он сидит или удалённо. Для одновременной работы нужен `Windows server` + лицензии на клиентов для `сервера терминалов`. В магазине не покупается, надо искать дистрибьютеров\интеграторов. Они и по железу подсказать могут. Но в любом случае: смотреть на то сколько памяти\проца жрёт обычный фотошоп на обычной машине + запас хотя бы в половину. И это - на одного человека.